# Why is anchor tag not working inside the footer element in C# asp,net mvc? The link is not clickable

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, anchor

In my mvc project, I have a cshtml file, wherein I have an anchor tag placed inside a footer element, which looks like this:

```
<footer class="login_footer">@Messages.msgCopyright | <a onclick="BeginSupportLoginMode();">Support Login</a></footer>
```

The problem here is that I am not able to click on the link when it is placed inside the footer element. The link was clickable when I tried putting it outside the footer element. I have tried finding solutions in several ways, but nothing has worked yet. Please suggest what should be done in this case.

Comment: `<footer class="login_footer">@Messages.msgCopyright | <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="BeginSupportLoginMode();">Support Login</a></footer>`

Comment: @HirenPatel, thank you for your response, I just tried what you suggested, but still the link is not clickable.

Comment: please share code in HTML snippet. with JS and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` is missing a `href` attribute. It is valid but it doesn't behave as a hyperlink (It is not tab-able or clickable). If it should be a clickable link, add a `href=""` attribute.

Comment: I tried adding the href tag, but it still doesn't work. The link is still not clickable.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't see that. If I take your code and add a `href`, the link gets clickable. Maybe there's something else that causing the issue that's not visible in the code snippet?

Comment: Yes, there seems to be something else that is causing the issue.